# Syntax error on token "-", invalid AssignmentOperator

Tags: java, user-interface, math

```
for (int iI = 4; iI > 0; iI--)
  faAmount[iI] - faAmount[iI - 1];
```

This is the code it's in. How can I fix this?

Comment: Do you mean `faAmount[iI] = faAmount[iI] - faAmount[iI - 1];`

Answer (score 5):

Maybe you forgot the equal sign

```
for (int iI = 4; iI > 0; iI--) 
    faAmount[iI] -= faAmount[iI - 1];
```

Or to assign the difference in a variable

```
double x = 0; //or another value
for (int iI = 4; iI > 0; iI--) 
    x = faAmount[iI] - faAmount[iI - 1];
```

Answer (score 2):

`faAmount[iI] - faAmount[iI - 1]` is n expression that have a result, but you don't assign it to anything, this is invalid in Java.

Answer (score 2):

The technical explanation is that `faAmount[iI] - faAmount[iI - 1]` is an expression but isn't a statement. [The JLS notes that](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.8)

> Unlike C and C++, the Java programming language allows only certain forms of expressions to be used as expression statements.

An additive expression is not one of those expressions that are also statements.